# Data deleting automatically with Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

We have a database with 2000 tables without any rows.

From time to time, new tables with rows get created and then cleaned up again, but the tables remain.

I need a script to delete or drop the tables in the current database that are older then a certain date.

We had a script which was working but suddenly stopped and somehow got removed.

Any assistance on how to create a new script that I can run as a policy?

We're using SQL Server 2016.

Thank you

We tried recreating the script but fails.

Tried to recover the script that we had on the SQL but it is gone.
Checked on a couple of links but only finding information on deleting of records and not tables.

Comment: Write a `DELETE` query and schedule it to run as a SQL Server Agent job. `We tried recreating the script but fails.` what script, what failed? `DELETE SomeTable where Created <DateAdd(d,-100,GetDate())` should work

Comment: You'll need dynamic SQL to build a list of tables to drop after checking the object's created date and row count. Please show us what you have tried so far any where it's not working.

Comment: *On the other hand*, if you want to delete old data from 2K tables, you need to design your database for the job. Writing a script that will work over 2K tables with possibly different columns is asking for trouble. SQL Server solves this with table partitioning, which is transparent to the applications and users. You can specify that each table is partitioned according to a partition schema, eg by month, or year and specify that different partitions are stored in different file groups. When the time comes, you can drop a partition or file group immediately, without affecting anyone

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys.tables to get all the tables and check for modification date and then create a dynamic sql to execute:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql = (select N'drop table ' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N';'
FROM sys.tables AS t
WHERE modify_date > limitDateToDelete AND type = 'U' -- Change your date or use parameter
order by object_id 
 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.','nvarchar(max)')

print @sql ;
-- caution below will ACTUALLY drop the tables.
-- review the output and then uncomment below line
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

So after doing testing and reading everyone messages I managed to get the following script to work

```
USE DB  
GO  
DECLARE @date date = GETDATE() - 30  
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(100)  
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT name  
FROM sys.tables  
WHERE create_date < @date AND @table_name != 'Job_Overview' AND @table_name != 'name';   OPEN table_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @table_name   
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   EXEC('DROP TABLE ' + @table_name)  
   FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @table_name  
END   
CLOSE table_cursor  
DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```

It shows the command has completed successfully but doesn't delete the tables.